# Linux command ambiguous redirect

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have a lab header called header.txt and I want to cat into my 3 C files
`cat ../header.txt > find -name *.c`

What is wrong with the above statement?

Comment: try: for i in *.c; do cat ../header.txt > $i; done;

Comment: I went to edit the question, but I couldn't decide exactly what you have as your actual command line.  Insert a blank line after your '3 C files', then indent the command text by 4 spaces, and remove the end backquotes (and insert any that appear in your actual command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The I/O redirection operators `<`, `>`, etc. all only take *one word* as their argument, and use that as a *filename*.  Anything else is considered part of the command line.

So when you run this:

```
cat ../header.txt > find -name *.c
```

It's exactly the same as this:

```
cat ../header.txt -name *.c > find
```

That's probably not going to do anything useful.

Another problem: your `*.c` isn't escaped or quoted, so bash will expand it rather than passing it to `find`.

---

You can do what you seem to want with `tee`, which accepts any number of arguments:

```
cat ../header.txt | tee *.c
```

And then you don't even need `cat` any more, really.

```
tee *.c < ../header.txt
```

Of course, you could just as well do this with `cp`.  Perhaps you meant to *append* to these files?  If so, pass `-a` to `tee` as well.

---

Interesting trivia: zsh and some other shells will let you have *multiple* `>` operators, which works just like `tee`.  (Multiple `<` is also allowed and works like `cat`.)

```
cat infile > outfile1 > outfile2
```

But you have to actually list every file individually, so you can't use this shortcut with a glob like `*.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Output redirection is for files, not commands. You'll need to process each file separately.

```
find -name *.c -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  cat ../header.txt >> $f   # Append instead of overwriting
done
```

As for the 'ambiguous redirect', you normally get that when you write something like:

```
... > *.c
```

and the glob `*.c` expands to more than one file.  For example:

```
$ echo "" >> *.c
-sh: *.c: ambiguous redirect
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix your C files with the lab's header using:

```
for file in *.c
do cat ../header.txt "$file" > x
   mv x "$file"
done
```

If this were going to be a production operation, you'd worry about using a unique file name as the temporary (I'm just assuming that if you're careless enough to have a file called `x` lying around, it doesn't contain anything important), and you would deal with interrupts etc and clean up the intermediate file.  You can meditate on whether it is better to use `mv` or `cp` to replace the original file — contemplate permissions, symbolic links, hard links and cleanup once again.