# bash cat a file from a another server to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, ambiguous

i am trying to do a basic command of cat to a variable and it does not work..

```
 lines="not working"
 sshpass -p triltest ssh root@ILCFS 'cat /var/try/check ' > $lines
 echo $lines 


./script.sh: line 34: $lines: ambiguous redirect
not working
```

the file exists. can anyone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command ambiguous redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766180/linux-command-ambiguous-redirect)

Comment: could be due to you having a space in the file name (and not protecting the $lines variable by quoting).  I would recommend testing with `not_working`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `` `command` `` or `$(command)`. I.e.

```
lines=$(sshpass -p triltest ssh root@ILCFS 'cat /var/try/check ')
echo "$lines"
```